# Query about Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-console

[image: What does that "1", which is circled in black, signifies?]

Hi, I was making an attempt to learn python using Jupyter Notebook. But after one or two practices I found that, "1" which is circled appears out of no where. It makes me wonder how it came and what does it signifies. Please Help!

Comment: seems it is number of line in your snippet

Comment: @AlykoffGali Thank You. That indeed is the number of lines of code.

Comment: @Georgy Thanks for the link. It's useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line-number, you can deactivate it under:
View --> Toggel line numbers.